# ion-datetime bind to epoch

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, momentjs, angular2-databinding

I have a model that requires the date/time as milliseconds in Unix Epoch format. I have tried using the Moment interface, Date | numeric as type and I can't seem to get it right.

I want the control to display in human readable format and the picker likewise but I want the databound model to be numeric. I can't use a pipe ("Cannot have a pipe in an action expression"). Should I remove the two way databinding, translate the value in the changeModel function and populate the person.date_of_birth with a similar function?

.html

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" pickerFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" (ngModelChange)="changeModel($event)" [(ngModel)]="person.date_of_birth"></ion-datetime>
```

.ts:

`let person={name: string, date_of_birth: numeric};`

The model is written to a local database on the mobile (pouchdb/sqlite) and then synched with a mongodb database via nodejs REST API. It is only displayed on this one html page so I'd really like it to be numeric everywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As input for your `ion-datetime`, you can use `public yourDate: string = new Date().toISOString();`. So this is the value you want to bind to your `ion-datetime`.

If you want to have another format, you can do something like this `new Date(yourDate).getTime()`. If you have this `ISOString`, you can always parse it back to a `Date` object.

**Update**

Working with a pipe and a format function.

Here we have a one-way databinding that is using my custom `date` pipe, thats formatting an numeric date to an `ISOString`.
The `(ngModelChange)` event is the "other-way" binding, thats assigning back a numeric value to `date_of_birth` (format is a custom function).

**page.html**

```
<ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" 
    (ngModelChange)="date_of_birth=format($event)" 
    [ngModel]="date_of_birth | date"></ion-datetime>
```

**date.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'date'
})
export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return new Date(value).toISOString();
  }

}
```

**page.ts**

```
date_of_birth: number = new Date().getTime();

format(val) {
  return new Date(val).getTime();
}
```

Working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-rw23d2?embed=1&file=pages/home/home.html)

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid. I have an array of person objects embedded in the parent; each with dob values. Doing it this way means populating local datatypes that differ from the model and handling each change individually. This negates the value of having two way binding. So either I have a htmlPerson type storing dates as strings and bind to that (convert prior to db write), or I have an array of dates as strings and synch that parameter with the model. Either way is ugly. It would be helpful if the ion-datetime could read/write epoch time and follow displayFormat for presentation.

Comment: Ok, you can use pipes for this aswell. I will edit my answer!

Comment: Please do. I was unsuccessful in getting pipes to work.

Comment: This should be a generic solution, for your problem.

Comment: Ah, one way binding allows pipes, that makes sense. I've renamed the date pipe as there's already a standard angular one of that name. And I used moment rather than the Date object. Other than that, this works great. Thanks for your time.